# Exception while adding TFS plugins

Tags: tfs

I have written a plugin for TFS 2010 to get notified instantly whenever any check-ins happens. However, the plugin does not work. I checked using windows event viewer and found the following error occured when the plugin dll is copied to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Application Tier\Web Services\bin\Plugins\" folder.

Exception:
Activation context generation failed for "C:\Windows\system32\conhost.exe". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.Windows.SystemCompatible,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df",type="win32",version="6.0.7600.16823" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

Does anybody know the solution? Any alternative? Any suggestion? Please let me know.

Thanks,
Chandan

Answer (score 1):

It might be an issue with being built against a particular processor architecture.  Try compiling your plugin for "Any Cpu", or if that doesn't work try flipping it to the opposite architecture (if it's x86, switch to x64, etc).

Also, TFS already has the capability of notifying you on checkins, out of the box!  The [Alerts Explorer](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=184258) and [notification system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181334.aspx) are really fancy, and may be better suited for what you're trying to do.